# How can I loop over a list of documents and execute commands on each in mongoose with async await

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, exec

I have users, posts and follows collection. I want to select posts, limit it to 10  and look their authors in follows collection whether user follow him or not. Also using async and await made me confusing. I tried this code

```
 async function index (req,res){
   const {user_id} = req.body
   const post  =  await Post.find().exec( async (err,doc)=>{
   const isFollowing = await Follows.find({who_id : user_id , whom_id : doc._id })
   if (isFollowing.length > 0){
    return doc
   }
 })
```

Then I figured out from VS Code that  if I use exec function "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can select 10 random posts and return only the one that the user follows between them with:

```
async function index (req,res)
{
    const { user_id } = req.body
    const posts = await Post.find().limit(10);
    const following = [];
    for (const post of posts) {
        const isFollowing = await Follows.find({ who_id : user_id , whom_id : post._id });
        if (isFollowing) following.push(post);
    }
    return following;
  })
```